# How to add setTimeout to OnClick function Show/Hide with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an onClick function that's show/hiding multiple divs depending on which div you click on. How can I get this to run automatically with a timer, changing every 5 seconds, as well as working with onClick? Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function($){

  $('.showSection').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetSection').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
}); 
    $('.showSection').first().click();
});
```

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8qw05um1/

Comment: is your code working fine otherwise i.e. on click? I mean, you just want it to also run every 5 seconds?

Comment: yes, it's working fine I just can't figure out how to add the setTimeout function without breaking it

Comment: ok wait. i'll give you a code sample for that.

Comment: Modify your question please. You want to run the click handler after X seconds? You want to run code that is in the click handler every X seconds (without having to click though)? Please make it more clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it will loop through the divs but also allow you to click to change. Since I broke out your click function into one that can be used for the click or the interval, you can change it if you want different behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function($){

  var options = $.makeArray( $('.showSection') );

  function doStuff() {
    var that;
    if (this === window) {
      that = options[0];
      options.push(options.shift());
    } else {
      that = this;
    }

    $(that).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetSection').hide();
    jQuery('#div' + jQuery(that).data('target')).show();
  }

  $('.showSection').on('click', doStuff); 

  setInterval(doStuff, 5000);

  $('.showSection').first().click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.showSection').on('click', function (e) {
        if( typeof showHideInterval != "undefined" )
        {
            clearInterval( showHideInterval );
        }//if
        var $this = $(this);
        showHideDivs( $this );
        showHideInterval = setInterval( showHideDivs, 2000, $this );
    });
    $('.showSection').first().click();
});

function showHideDivs( $this )
{
    $this.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetSection').hide();
    $('#div' + $this.data('target')).show();
}//showHideDivs()
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding this in the fiddle and it doesn't seem to be working - am I missing something? https://jsfiddle.net/8qw05um1/1/

Comment: @jgb please try now. But it keeps clicking the same element after 2s in this case. I mean, it doesn't loop through the multiple divs. Is that fine or you want to loop through the list?

Comment: Thank you, Mike! Works just fine!